# How to prevent indentation errors?

Tags: python, scripting, text-editor

I added a line and am very sure there is no indentation problem. Here is the error report and screenshots of the text so you can see it:

> Error: File "C:\Users\info\Desktop\Claas UI.blend\Claas_UI_2.py", line 40
>       bpy.ops.object.mode_set( mode = 'EDIT' )
>
> TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation
>   location: :-1
>
> Error: Python script fail, look in the console for now...

[image]
[image]

When I remove the line with the arrows and uncoment the previous lines below it all runs fine.

[image]

Any idea what causes this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Python doesn't like inconsitently mixed tabs and spaces for indentation.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd> opens the property panel, check that the *Tabs as Spaces* is ticked.

You can usually fix this by unindenting the lines in question by <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> to the first column and re-indent them <kbd>Tab</kbd> again.

[image]

There is also the menu option available  *`Format > Convert Whitespace > To Spaces`*  (or to tabs)

Related:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5685406/inconsistent-use-of-tabs-and-spaces-in-indentation

Comment: This is rather bizarre. I use tabs from the beginning and not spaces. So I reset all tab steps and then formatted the text again. It worked. Must have by accident adjusted some text via spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Recently I faced a similar problem. I was using the sublime editor. it's not an issue with the code but with the editor.

Below change in the preference settings worked for me.

Sublime Text menu -> Preferences -> Settings: Syntax-Specific:

{ "tab_size": 4, "translate_tabs_to_spaces": true }

Answer (score 0):

That error was driving me crazy.
To solve on Visual Studio Code. Click with mouse right button, and select **Command Palette** on your code, and after that select de command **'Convert Indentation to Tabs'**